# Read data from an API and populate the database without duplicate in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

```
Controller code to view the API records

    public function index()
    {
        $client=new Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.publicapis.org/entries');
        $apidata = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);

        return view('apidata')->with('apidata', $apidata ['entries']);

  }
```

```
to store the records into db
    public function store()
    {
        set_time_limit(240);
        $client=new Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.publicapis.org/entries');
        $apidata = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);

        foreach($apidata ['entries'] as $entries) {
            $entries = Apidata::updateorCreate([
                'API'=> $entries['API'],
                'Description'=>$entries['Description'],
                'Auth'=>$entries['Auth'],
                'HTTPS'=>$entries['HTTPS'],
                'Cors'=>$entries['Cors'],
                'Link'=>$entries['Link'],
                'Category'=>$entries['Category']
            ]);
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Data Saved Successfully!');

    }
}
```

Get records from external API
Save all the records into database
The records must not be duplicated in case we send multiple API calls
also how do i save the records in batch to avoid maximum time out for large entries

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question. What did you want to know?

Comment: i want to save the data without duplicates, even if I run it several times, also how to running it without the time limit, I had to set a time limit above the normal limit by default

Answer (score 0):

In your case you were using updateOrCreate method. So you can set a primary key field to determine if the same record occurs again, it will automatically just update the same record with the primary column.

Let us assume - "Auth" is a primary column, then you can save the records with updateOrCreate method as follows,

```
$entries = Apidata::updateorCreate(
    [
        'API' => $entries['API'],
    ],
    [
        'API' => $entries['API'],
        'Description' => $entries['Description'],
        'Auth' => $entries['Auth'],
        'HTTPS' => $entries['HTTPS'],
        'Cors' => $entries['Cors'],
        'Link' => $entries['Link'],
        'Category' => $entries['Category']
    ]
);
```

In such way you can avoid duplicate entries in laravel 9

Comment: Thanks, but not clear.

Comment: @S.Radje If you check with laravel upsert concept you'll get more idea in it. Please refer this [Upsert](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts)